# How to determine which display a program is rendered on by X

Tags: bash, xorg, xfce

I'm trying to write a bash script which will use pywal to set a custom theme for my xfce4-terminal based on the background image that the xfce4-terminal window is rendered on. Currently, I'm using xfconf-query to get the desktop background image manually based on my displays, but I would like to be able to dynamically get this information so I can transfer to new installs or distribute to other people. I would also like for the script to detect when I move my terminal to a different monitor (which would have a different wallpaper) This is what is currently being used to get the wallpaper for my main display only:

`wallpaper="$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen0/monitorDP-4/workspace0/last-image)"`

This part is what I would like to be able to get dynamically based on what window the terminal is rendered on:

`/backdrop/screen0/monitorDP-4/workspace0/last-image`

Is this something that could be done relatively easily? Full code below in case that helps

```
#!/bin/bash

#background_monitor.sh
#runs pywal when xfce background changes
#to do:
#1. figure out how to find what window terminal is running on then adjust for that
#2. figure out how to dynamically get /backdrop/screen0/ part so it works on other installs


wallpaper2=""
#I think I'll eventually need to get the terminal PID maybe?
#terminalPID=$(ps -ef | grep xfce4-terminal | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}')

#this part is for passing arguments if you want to run the script from cmdline only
if [ "$1" = "1" ]
then
    wallpaper="$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen0/monitorDP-4/workspace0/last-image)"
    break
elif [ "$1" = "2" ]
then
    wallpaper="$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen0/monitorHDMI-0/workspace0/last-image)"
    break
fi

#this part is for running it from .bashrc so it is running when I open a term window
#currently defaults to my main display. Maybe there's a better way than infinite while loop and running from bashrc?
while :
do
    wallpaper="$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen0/monitorDP-4/workspace0/last-image)"

    ##get which monitor terminal is currently running on would go here

    #run pywal to change terminal theme to match current desktop background
    while [ "$wallpaper" != "$wallpaper2" ]
    do
        wal -i $wallpaper -n -q
        wallpaper2="$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen0/monitorDP-4/workspace0/last-image)"

    done
    sleep 3
done
```

Comment: You want to be careful when you execute a script from '.bashrc'. The '.bashrc' is excecuted in many situations - not just when a terminal is launched. Consider setting a flag to protect against repeated run. Also, consider checking for "$DISPLAY" to make sure there is a display currently setup.

Comment: That's a good point - I'll add a check for if it's already running. Checking for $DISPLAY would basically keep it from running on a tty without a desktop running, right? Where do you think would be a better place to run from than bashrc? xinitrc maybe?

Comment: I believe '.xinitrc' is better place. It will only execute one time per session, and only under X - no need for the extra checks in this case.